# Is it possible to hide map annotations?

Tags: qgis, annotation

I have several annotations in my map that disturb.

Is it possible to hide them somehow and show them later when I need them?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Toggle the **Text Annotation** function in the toolbar and press *Ctrl + T* to switch it on/off:

[image: Text annotation]

---

**EDIT:**

*The above keyboard shortcut only affects text annotations.*

There is the *experimental* **Annotations manager** plugin which allows you to enable/disable/remove annotations in your project. Note that it only affects the following annotation types:

- Text
- Form
- SVG

I.e. it does not currently support HTML annotations. You can download this from the menubar:

```
Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...
```

[image: Annotations manager plugin]

Comment: If I press Ctrl + T all my layers activate, but annotations don't disappear..

Comment: @Egidi - Apologies, you're absolutely right (I assumed the keyboard shortcut affected all annotations). I've edited my post ;)

Comment: Also note that the current version of the plugin is a little unstable and may crash your QGIS...

Comment: The Annotation Manager plugin seems less experimental these days. Works pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

you could also use an annotation layer: In the Annotations Toolbar click "New Annotation Layer". If you already have annotations use the "Transfer annotations from main layer" function in the Processing Toolbox to transfer the annotations to the newly created annotation layer. You can then toggle the layer visibility. (QGIS 3.26)

Comment: Note: You need QGIS 3.22 or higher to use Annotation Layers